# Working out formula and displaying the value on a label reading user input

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically I would like the user to input 3 values into a textbox and have a button that calculates the total of the 3 inputted values. I thought I could read the user input and then convert it into an integer and from that apply a formula to work out fnum+snum+tnum = total; What I have done so far does not work can anybody guide me thanks.

```
         int num1 = int.Parse(weighting1.Text);
         int num2 = int.Parse(weighting2.Text);
         int num3 = int.Parse(weighting3.Text);
         total = num1+num2+num3;
         int total = int.parse(lTotal.Text);
         // Code to display the variable
```

Comment: Could you be more specific re: does not work?  Doesn't compile?  Doesn't handle roman numerals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of int.parse(lTotal.Text) you need to assign total's string value to label

```
lTotal.Text = total.ToSTring();
```

Your code should be:

```
 int num1 = int.Parse(weighting1.Text);
 int num2 = int.Parse(weighting2.Text);
 int num3 = int.Parse(weighting3.Text);
 int total = num1+num2+num3;
 lTotal.Text = total.ToSTring();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `lTotal` is your label and you want to put the value of `total` into the Text of the label?  If so:

```
lTotal.Text = total.ToString()
```

Your current code goes in the other direction... it reads whatever is currently the Text of the Label lTotal, attempts to parse that text as an integer, and assigns it to total.  You also redeclare total in that line (`int total`, whereas you use `total` in the preceding line) which should not compile.